# Background Sprite Setting

Tags: 2d, unity, sprites, camera

For my 2d game, I want to set background image. So that I am using multiple background images for that purpose.

But it can't set correctly on screen that illustrated in following image.
[image]

Also for setting background correctly, I am calculating camera orthographic size based current resolution and loading that sprite dynamically.

My camera inspector setting illustrated in following image.

[image]

My basic target is to display my background image in full screen without any bar. For example, If I have resolution of 600x1024 resolution and I am loading same resolution image then it should be display in full screen.

But you see that I can't able to get this result. So please some one help me to come out of this. If you want any more detail then I will provide at any time.

Comment: I'm quite puzzled "without any bar" what is a bar? Is it that 2 bars on top and on bottom in your screenshot? Or are you just wanted your BG image to stretch 'adaptively' to any resolution?

Comment: At present, my background is of correct size as of current resolution setting. But it don't match with resolution and look really small. That clearly seen in screen shot. So I want it fit to current resolution. Although I am not talking any different resolution but present 1080x1920 only.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to proceed is to use the gameobject Quad.

Assign the texture to the Quad you want to use as the background and scale it just enough to cover your viewport. 
This way you wont have to adjust according to the resolution and Unity will scale accordingly according to the screen res.

One more advantage is that Quad is basically a (kind of )2d Object in a 3d space with ability to move it in the game screen so it will be easy for you to position it accordingly. makes your designing easier and simpler :)

Comment: I up vote your answer but this is not what I expect as answer because if I have painted background not plain as here then this solution not work for me.